# Is it possible to implement Philips Hue in this?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have not begun making this yet, but can you tell me if it is possible to implement Hue commands into this?

[Steven Hickinson](http://stevenhickson.blogspot.dk/2013/06/voice-command-v30-for-raspberry-pi.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Philips Hue base station (or hub or whatever you call it) exposes a REST service which you can consume to use with the voice commands.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can tou tell me if it's possible to make a GUI that postes all the responses from the voice command instead of showing it in terminal?

Comment: Yes, that should be possible as well